# Decrease response time in Firebase Vue app when liking a post

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuex, lag

I have an app with different 'procedures' (think posts or pages), which one can like. Currently the process works: Tap like => run method "likeProcedure" => run dispatch action "likeProcedure" => update UI. It usually happens almost immediately, but sometimes there's a lag that gives this a "non-native" feel. Is there some sort of way that I could return feedback immediately, while stile holding single origin of truth on the firebase database?

Thank you!

Page Code:

```
<v-icon
  v-if="!userProfile.likedProcedures || !userProfile.likedProcedures[procedure.id]"
  color="grey lighten-1"
  @click="likeProcedure({ id: procedure.id })"
>
  mdi-star-outline
</v-icon>
```

and

```
computed: {
  ...mapState(["userProfile"]),
  procedures() {
    return this.$store.getters.getFilteredProcedures();
  },
},
```

Vuex code:

```
async likeProcedure({ dispatch }, postId) {
      const userId = fb.auth.currentUser.uid;
      // update user object
      await fb.usersCollection.doc(userId).update({
        [`likedProcedures.${postId.id}`]: true,
      });

      dispatch("fetchUserProfile", { uid: userId });
    },
```

Side note: I'm trying to remove the `dispatch("fetchUserProfile")` command, but this doesn't work, because then I'm calling `dispatch` without using it. And I cannot remove `dispatch` because then the object calling it is empty. And I cannot remove the object, because then the argument `('postId')` isn't working. So if anyone knows how to deal with that, that would be extremely helpful.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the best solution I've come up yet. It kind of destroys the idea of a single source of truth, but at least it provides an immediate UI update:

```
  async likeProcedure({ dispatch, state }, postId) {
    console.log("likeProcedure");
    const userId = fb.auth.currentUser.uid;

    // line below provides immediate update to state and hence to the UI
    state.userProfile.likedProcedures[postId.id] = true;

    // line below updates Firebase database
    await fb.usersCollection.doc(userId).update({
      [`likedProcedures.${postId.id}`]: state.userProfile.likedProcedures[
        postId.id
      ],
    });

    // line below then fetches the updated profile from Firebase and updates
    // the profile in state. Kind of useless, but ensures that client and
    // Firebase are  in-sync
    dispatch("fetchUserProfile", { uid: userId });
  },

  async fetchUserProfile({ commit }, user) {
    // fetch user profile
    const userProfile = await fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid).get();

    // set user profile in state
    commit("setUserProfile", userProfile.data());

    // change route to dashboard
    if (router.currentRoute.path === "/login") {
      router.push("/");
    }
  },
```